# Is there any way to completely disable pageSizeLimit [yii2]

Tags: php, api, rest, yii2

yii2 REST API uses `ActiveDataProvider`to fetch and show data. This class has `pageSizeLimit` ([docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html#$pageSizeLimit-detail)) parameter which by default limit our `pageSize` to 50, so no matter how high is `per-page` (`pageSizeParam`) query parameter, maximum 50 rows are returned.

Is there any way to completely disable `pageSizeLimit` so that provider will show as many rows as we want by specifying `per-page` query parameter or `defaultPageSize` if not specified? Setting pageSizeLimit to false forces to always return `defaultPageSize` rows no matter what we pass by per-page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set `pageSizeLimit` to an empty array in *dataProvider* configuration.

```
'pagination' => [
    'pageSizeLimit' => [1]
]
```

As you can see from [source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/Pagination.php#L211), if `pageSizeLimit` parameter is empty yii2 uses *defaultPageSize* parameter, else tries to set page size from *$_GET* parameter. So if you set `pageSizeLimit` to array with one element (or anything else but not *false* or *[x,y]* array), [setPageSize()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/Pagination.php#L230) will not check the limit and set pageSize to value from *$_GET*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but setting it to empty has the same effect as setting it to `false`, so it locks on `defaultPageSize` parameter.

Comment: Investigating the source code, I've found out that setting `pageSizeLimit` to anything, but `false` and two-dimensional array will work, so basically setting it even to `pageSizeLimit` => [10] will work also, and it will ignore this setting at all. In conclusion, I don't think that it is right and I will file issue, and for now update your answer with this info and I will accept your answer for other's reference.